# PEAR::HTTP/Request2 doesn't follow redirect

Tags: php, pear

When scrapping i. e. http://baidu.com, script doesn't follow `<meta.. refresh..>` redirect. The code I'm running:

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new HTTP_Request2("http://baidu.com", HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$request->setConfig(array(
    'adapter' => 'HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Curl',
    'connect_timeout' => 15,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'follow_redirects' => TRUE,
    'max_redirects' => 10,
));

try {
    $response = $request->send();
    if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {

        $html = $response->getBody();
    } else {
        echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
        $response->getReasonPhrase();
    }
} catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

print $html;
```

outputs:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.baidu.com/">
</html>
```

Is there a way to make it follow this redirect, to get proper html in $response->getBody()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PEAR library does follow HTTP redirects since these are declared in the request header. The example you show in your question is an HTML meta refresh - a different mechanism.

What you'll want to do is read the response to the HTTP request made via PEAR and parse the "meta refresh" tag, then make a second request to the URI that you managed to scrape out of the first request.

Below is an example of a function that will do this taken from a comment left on the PHP manual.

```
function getUrlContents($url, $maximumRedirections = null, $currentRedirection = 0)
{
 $result = false;

$contents = @file_get_contents($url);

// Check if we need to go somewhere else

if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
{
    preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*http-equiv="?REFRESH"?' . '[\s]*content="?[0-9]*;[\s]*URL[\s]*=[\s]*([^>"]*)"?' . '[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 2 && count($match[1]) == 1)
    {
        if (!isset($maximumRedirections) || $currentRedirection < $maximumRedirections)
        {
            return getUrlContents($match[1][0], $maximumRedirections, ++$currentRedirection);
        }

        $result = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $contents;
    }
}

return $contents;
}
```

This snippet was found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

As I explained, you can do something like the following:

```
//get the url from the meta redirect tag
$url = getUrlContents($site1);
//set up the new request in PEAR
$request = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
```

You may want to re-implement the getURLContents function so that it uses PEAR to get the first URL if this is your preferred method for making HTTP calls.